# Why do `foo == bar` and `bar == foo` return different results?

Tags: ruby

What is going on here? Why does a position of sides in `==` comparison change the output?

```
secret == BCrypt::Password.new(BCrypt::Password.create(secret)) 
# => false 
BCrypt::Password.new(BCrypt::Password.create(secret)) == secret
# => true
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out the values of `BCrypt::Password.new(BCrypt::Password.create(secret))`, maybe they're not what you think...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the return value of `BCrypt::Password.new` is of `BCrypt::Password` which overrides `==`

http://bcrypt-ruby.rubyforge.org/classes/BCrypt/Password.html#M000009

> Compares a potential secret against the hash. Returns true if the
>   secret is the original secret, false otherwise.

So when `secret` is on the left, its equals method is being used (which is doing string comparison), whereas when the hash is on the left, it is actually comparing against the original secret

Comment: Thanks. I thought this was the case, however it was still very confusing. The doc explains it all. I think I will use .is_password? method instead of == to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is that `==` is `LHS#==`, that is to say, that `==` is not a universal operator, like in C or C++ or Java, but rather a function called on the object on the left hand side.

Without knowing more about your code, it's difficult to tell you exactly what's going on.

In simple terms, `secret.class#==` must be behaving differently than `BCrypt::Password#==`. Perhaps BCrypt::Password knows how to compare an encrypted string (itself) and an unencrypted string (the argument), whereas `secret`, if it's a string, has no knowledge of how to compare `BCrypt::Password` to itself.

Answer (score 1):

BCrypt::Password has a == method to compare to secret.

```
BCrypt::Password.new(BCrypt::Password.create(secret)).class
 => BCrypt::Password
```

So

```
BCrypt::Password.new(BCrypt::Password.create(secret)) == secret
 => true
```

The other expression doesn't call the method == on BCrypt::Password, but the one on string.

http://bcrypt-ruby.rubyforge.org/classes/BCrypt/Password.html#M000009

Comment: Just finding out that when Ruby says everything is a method, they mean it. Coming from world where == used to mean one thing and one thing only.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is an object-oriented language. In OO, the receiver of a message send gets to decide how to respond to that message. In your case, the two receivers are not only different objects, they are even different *types* of objects.

There are some standard double-dispatch protocols in Ruby which are intended to ensure that some operators are symmetric, but a) those protocols exist only for arithmetic operations on numbers not for equality, and b) there's no guarantee that an object follows those protocols.

In short, in OO, there is no way to ensure symmetry of operators. That's just a fundamental property of OO.